# How do I run a query from Excel VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

The following code creates a new access database and copies tables from two different access databases into the new one. This part works without error.

The problem is on the following line: `TMPConnection.Open TMPConnectionString`
It notifies that the file is already in use.

```
Dim strPath As String
Dim objAccess As Object
Dim dbss As Object
Dim fso As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
strPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Desktop\TMP.accdb"
'DETERMINE IF DB ALREADY EXISTS AND CREATE IF IT DOES NOT
strDb = Dir(strPath)
Set objAccess = CreateObject("Access.Application")
If Len(strDb) <> 0 Then
    fso.DeleteFile strPath
End If
Call objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strPath)
Set dbss = objAccess.CurrentDb
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'COPY ACCESS DATABASE TABLES INTO THE NEWLY CREATED TMP DATABASE
objAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fileNameNEW, acTable, arr1(i), "N"
objAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fileNameNEW, acTable, arr2(i), "O"
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'CONNECT TO DATABASE
Dim TMPConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim TMPRecordsetN As ADODB.Recordset
Dim TMPRecordsetO As ADODB.Recordset
Dim TMPQueryN As String
Dim TMPQueryO As String
Set TMPRecordsetN = New ADODB.Recordset
Set TMPRecordsetO = New ADODB.Recordset
Set TMPConnection = New ADODB.Connection
TMPConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strPath
TMPConnection.Open TMPConnectionString
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TMPQueryN = "Select * from " & "N"
TMPQueryO = "Select * from " & "O"
Set TMPRecordsetN = TMPConnection.Execute(TMPQueryN)
Set TMPRecordsetO = TMPConnection.Execute(TMPQueryO)
'--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Worksheets("NEW").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset TMPRecordsetN
```

I am not sure how to use this "already existing" connection to execute the queries `Set TMPRecordsetN = TMPConnection.Execute(TMPQueryN)` (**TMPConnection**)

**My question is:**
If there already exists a connection to this new database, how can I use it to run the queries (e.g. TMPRecordsetN)

Comment: `Set TMPRecordsetN = dbss.OpenRecordset(TMPQueryN)`

Comment: Don't Execute SELECT queries. Execute is for Action SQL (DELETE, INSERT, UPDATE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially, you are connecting to MS Access in two different ways: frontend with the Access COM object and backend with ADO. Additionally, you are combining two DB APIs, DAO with `CurrentDb` and ADO with `ADODB.Connection`, which both have recordset objects.

Consider either using first connection via the Access COM application and DAO or close the COM object and connect to new database with ADO.

**Approach 1: Run all operations with COM connection and DAO**

```vb
...
Call objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strPath)

objAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fileNameNEW, acTable, arr1(i), "N"
objAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fileNameNEW, acTable, arr2(i), "O"

' INITIALIZE DAO DATABASE
Set dbss = objAccess.CurrentDb

' OPEN DAO RECORDSETS
TMPQueryN = "SELECT * FROM [N]"
TMPQueryO = "SELECT * FROM [O]"
Set TMPRecordsetN = dbss.OpenRecordset(TMPQueryN)
Set TMPRecordsetO = dbss.OpenRecordset(TMPQueryO)

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEW").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset TMPRecordsetN

' CLOSE AND RELEASE DAO OBJECTS
TMPRecordsetN.Close: TMPRecordsetO.Close
Set TMPRecordsetN = Nothing: Set TMPRecordsetO = Nothing: Set dbss = Nothing

' CLOSE AND RELEASE COM OBJECT
objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase
objAccess.Quit

Set objAccess = Nothing
```

**Approach 2: Close COM connection without DAO and open ADO connection**

```vb
...
Call objAccess.NewCurrentDatabase(strPath)

objAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fileNameNEW, acTable, arr1(i), "N"
objAccess.DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "Microsoft Access", fileNameNEW, acTable, arr2(i), "O"

' CLOSE AND RELEASE COM OBJECT
objAccess.CloseCurrentDatabase()
objAccess.Quit()

Set objAccess = Nothing


' CONNECT TO DATABASE VIA ADO -----------------------------------------------------
Dim TMPConnection As ADODB.Connection
Dim TMPRecordsetN As ADODB.Recordset, TMPRecordsetO As ADODB.Recordset
Dim TMPQueryN As String, TMPQueryO As String

' OPEN CONNECTION
Set TMPConnection = New ADODB.Connection
MPConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & "Data Source=" & strPath
TMPConnection.Open TMPConnectionString

' OPEN ADO RECORDSETS
Set TMPRecordsetN = New ADODB.Recordset
TMPQueryN = "SELECT * FROM [N]"
TMPRecordsetN.Open TMPQueryN, TMPConnection

Set TMPRecordsetO = New ADODB.Recordset
TMPQueryO = "SELECT * FROM [O]"
TMPRecordsetO.Open TMPQueryO, TMPConnection

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NEW").Range("A1").CopyFromRecordset TMPRecordsetN

' CLOSE AND RELEASE ADO OBJECTS
TMPRecordsetO.Close: TMPRecordsetN.Close: TMPConnection.Close
Set TMPRecordsetO = Nothing: Set TMPRecordsetN = Nothing: Set TMPConnection = Nothing
```